# setFrame does not work when I add UIKit elements to a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, frame

I have the view as you can see below:
[image: view three]

When I try to collapse **schedinaContView** in a **CGSizeZero** frame, it works only if the schedina's subviews are empty.

This is my code:

```
-(void)prepareFloatSchedina
{
    schedinaVC = [[SchedinaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SchedinaViewController" bundle:nil];
    schedinaVC.view.frame = self.schedina.frame;
    [self.schedina addSubview: schedinaVC.view];

    schedinaExpandedSize = _schedinaContView.frame.size;
    CGRect frame = [UIUtilCollection frameInSuperFrame:self.view.frame atCornerWithSize:schedinaCompressedSize];
    _schedinaContView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(NSStringFromCGRect(_schedinaContView.frame));

    UIButton *bottone = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [bottone setTitle:@"Ciao" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.schedina addSubview:bottone];
}
```

This is the result of the NSLog:

> {{1004, 748}, {0, 0}}

But _schedinaContView is still present in the view!

So, if I remove the UIButton, it perfectly works. That's why?

**RESOLVED:**

I solved setting to YES the param of the method `[translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:]`
Then I deactivated the NSLayoutConstraint on the focused view and I reactivated when I try to open the view.

```
[_schedinaContView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
_verticalSpace.active = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I see autolayout constraints. `setFrame` doesn't work with autolayout.
Use constraints instead `setFrame` or turnoff autolayout.

Comment: Yes, I use it. I also tried using [ updateConstraints] after setFrame, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LucaD, you don't need `setFrame` at all if you use autolayout. Also it's better to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` to avoid autolayout collisions.

Comment: Ok, but reading the documentation about AutoLayout I read about the param to that method = YES. However, I think I solved, I will explain it in the next answer